# git how to merge merges from a specific author?

Tags: git, merge

Im looking for a simple solution to merge some specific merges from the master into the release branch.

```
dev ---A---B---C---D---...   
        \ / \ / \ / \ /
master --A---B---C---D-...
          \
release ---A------------
```

Lets say Author 1 merged B and D into the master and these merges should be also in the release Branch but not C. 
I found the cherry-pick but that doesnt seems to be the right function to do that.
so my question is how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think cherry-pick is not what you need?
To me it seems that `git cherry-pick` is exactly what you want.

**Start:**

```
master --A---B---C---D-...
          \
release ---A
```

**First:**

```
git checkout release
git cherry-pick B

master --A---B---C---D-...
          \
release ---A--B'
```

**Second:**

```
git cherry-pick D

master --A---B---C---D-...
          \
release ---A--B'--D'
```

Always remember that `cherry-pick` creates a new commit!
Afterwards I would merge `release` into `master`.
If you want to get rid of `C` you have to use `revert` before or after the merge.

**Finally:**

```
git checkout master
git merge release

master --A---B---C---D-...----X
          \                  / 
release ---A--B'--D'---------
```

Comment: I thought I also need the merge commits, but I tried it with cherry-pick now and took all non merge commits that I needed. It looks like it would have worked. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome! Cherry-picking is a little tricky at the beginning :)